# Convert Pine Script v1 to v4

Tags: pine-script

Please see below an indicator I found on Trading View.
My goal is to combine it with other indicators to develop a trading strategy.
Since other indicators are made using the Pine Script version 4,
I need to make sure that this indicator is compatible with version 4.
When I add //@version=4 on top, it gives an error.
It looks like there is something wrong. Could anybody please help me to fix this?

Thank you very much!

```
//@version=1

study(title="Bar Color", overlay = true)
src = close, len = input(11)
p1= ema(src,len)


ut   = close > p1 and close[1] > p1 
dt = close < p1 and close[1] < p1

uc = close > close[1] or high > high[1] and low > low[1]
dc = close < close[1] or high < high[1] and low < low[1]


showbar = (ut and uc) ? #00FFFF :
   (ut and dc) ? #00FFFF :
   (dt and dc) ? #FF0066 :
   (dt and uc) ? #FF0066 :
   na

barcolor(color=showbar)
```

Comment: It is running correctly in by changing version to 4 in the first line, what error are you getting

Comment: I've tried change first line from 1 to 4 but it gives a error: line 15: Syntax error at input 'end of line without line continuation'.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the line 15 as one line

```
//@version=4

study(title="Bar Color", overlay = true)
src = close, len = input(11)
p1= ema(src,len)


ut   = close > p1 and close[1] > p1 
dt = close < p1 and close[1] < p1

uc = close > close[1] or high > high[1] and low > low[1]
dc = close < close[1] or high < high[1] and low < low[1]


showbar = (ut and uc) ? #00FFFF :   (ut and dc) ? #00FFFF :   (dt and dc) ? #FF0066 :   (dt and uc) ? #FF0066 :   na

barcolor(color=showbar)
```